# knockout js $index() binding not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am creating a DataGrid and a Pager using KnockOut JS.

The pager is like this:

```
<ul class="grdPager" data-bind="foreach: new Array(StudentGridSettings().totalPages)">
    <li><a href='#' data-bind="click: function() {TurnStudentListPage($index()+1)}, text: ($index()+1), style: { color : ($index()+1) == StudentGridSettings().pageIndex ? 'black' :'blue'} "></a></li>
</ul>
```

Dashboard.TurnStudentListPage(i) is a function that changes the value of Dashboard.StudentGridSettings().pageIndex. Everything else works fine. However the color of the links don't change when the page changes. Only the first li gets black color the rest stay blue even if the pageIndex is changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `pageIndex` is a ko.observable? Because then it should be  `StudentGridSettings().pageIndex()`...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No pageIndex is not observable, but StudentGridSettings is. Do I need to update it too?

Comment: Can you post your `TurnStudentListPage` function? By the way your `pageIndex` should be an observable...

Comment: I tried observable inside observable but it's now working (it broke other things too).

Comment: If you have problems with the nested observables then you need to use the `valueHasMutated` as I described in my answer. But nesting observables also should work I've also attached a JSFiddle sample for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the value of property inside of an observable KO won't be notified.
So even if your `StudentGridSettings` is an observable if you write `StudentGridSettings().pageIndex = something` KO won't know that the `StudentGridSettings` has been changed so it does not update your binding.

You can trigger the bindings with the `valueHasMutated` method, so you need to change your `TurnStudentListPage` to something like:

```
self.TurnStudentListPage = function(index){
    self.StudentGridSettings().pageIndex = index; 
    self.StudentGridSettings.valueHasMutated();
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4adQ/).

Or just declare your `pageIndex` property as an `ko.observable` and use in in your binding:

```
data-bind="style: { color : ($index()+1) == StudentGridSettings().pageIndex() ? 'black' :'blue'}"
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrfv/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. But can you please suggest me something here please (I have removed other ajax stuff):
[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dharmbhav/5jR2z/)
Thanks

Comment: I've fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mJ3n4/. The `valueHasMutated` is a method of the observable: so you need to write `Dashboard.StudentGridSettings.valueHasMutated();` see no `()` after `StudentGridSettings`. And as I wrote in my answer you need to write this in your `TurnStudentListPage` method and not in the init.